# How to add file to github repo in python

Tags: python, github

I have a folder inside a branch in a repository. I want to add a file to that folder from python. I looked at the github api docs but the examples are in js and it is confusing to me. Can anyone give an example of how to add a file to a github repo in python? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few options:

1. Use PyGit2 which binds libgit2: https://www.pygit2.org/
2. Use GitPython which wraps calls to `git` binary: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html
3. Call `git` binary directly using `subprocess.run`